# FMX: Setting TScrollBar thumb size by changing ViewportSize reduces maximum settable value

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Add a TScrollBar to a form in FMX and leave min and max at the default values 0 and 100. Set ViewportSize to 50. This makes the thumb half then length of the scroll bar. However, the value for the scroll bar can now only be set between 0 and 50. It seems that the maximum settable value is Max - ViewportSize. How can I set the thumb size while still being able to set values between 0 and Max? I know that I could set Max to 150 (Max + ViewportSize) but I'm already using Max in my code to determine what the maximum settable value is.

I note that the documentation is no help at all. It doesn't mention this issue and also incorrectly states that ViewportSize is in pixels.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TScrollBar.ViewportSize

Comment: I don't know, but think the logic goes like this: If your scrollable area is 100 high and your viewport size is 50 high, then you only need to scroll 50 to move from seeing the top 50 (of your scrollable area) to see the bottom 50, no? Why would you want the bottom border of the scrollable area to be scrolled to the top of your viewport?

Comment: I don't expect the bottom of the thumb to go to the top of the area, but I expect the value to still range between min and max by making the divisions smaller. When viewport size is 0 the thumb is not 0 size. I'm really looking for a way to increase that size without changing viewport size since it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Comment: I've now solved my issue by setting ViewportSize and then using Max - ViewportSize wherever I was previously using Max. However, I'd still be interested to know if it's possible to change the thumb size without setting ViewportSize. Perhaps by changing the scroll bar style?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what's happening. If your scrollable area is 100 high and you set the viewport size to 50, you only have 50 to scroll (because 50 are always visible). That means that the max is 50 - you have nowhere to go outside that range.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I think I see what the viewport size is now. My issue is in porting code from VCL to FMX. In VCL you set the thumb size using PageSize and it doesn't affect the scrollable range. In VCL I set PageSize to 1 when I want the thumb to change size as Max changes. To do the same in FMX I have to set ViewportSize to 1 but also increase Max by 1. There's no equivalent of PageSize.